# last-child last-child'а в css

Tags: html, css, выборка, border, margin

Есть css код для определенных списков:

```
section #contacts #contacts-list ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    border-left: 2px dotted #1C1C1C;
}
section #contacts #contacts-list ul li {
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
    section #contacts #contacts-list ul li:first-child {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
```

И таких списков на сайте несколько. Проблема в том, что из-за свойства margin-bottom у элемента списка, в конце немного выпирает border. Можно ли как-то отобрать последний элемент последнего списка? Я пробовал такой код:

```
section #contacts #contacts-list ul:last-child li:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Но, естественно, это не работает. И мне нужно конкретно на css, без применения js.

Comment: html код добавьте

Comment: попробуй выбрать ul:last-of-type

Comment: @ИльяШишлачев , Я пробовал li:last-of-type. Но все равно выбирается li внутри ul. А в ul:last-of-type не вижу смысла, margin мне нужен конкретно у li.

Comment: а что мешает добавить модификатор нужному элементу и переопределить стили?

Answer (score 0):

`li:last-child` поменяй `li:last-of-type`

```
section #contacts #contacts-list ul:last-child li:last-of-type { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

так заработает

Comment: Не работает. Браузер просто игнорирует стиль как неправильный.

Comment: попробуй поменять все last-child на last-of-type.

Comment: если тебе нужен последний `li`, то либо `section #contacts #contacts-list ul:last-child`, либо `section #contacts #contacts-list ul li:last-of-type`. оно не может быть неверным